# Granted, these are obscure

Tags: riddle, knowledge, music

Nothing's shocking through the looking glass.

Shade with teeth.

In your face manslaughter.

Weird revolution turned on.

Commercial entertainment product 3.

What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## EXTREMELY HELLA DONE EDITION

They are

> Album titles
>
>  **1A** - *Nothing's Shocking* - Jane's Addiction (1988)
>  **1B** - *Through the Looking Glass* - Siouxsie and the Banshees (1987)
>  **2A** - *Shade* - Living Colour (2016)
>  **2B** - *With Teeth* - Nine Inch Nails (2005)
>  **3A** - *In Your Face* - Fishbone (1986)
>  **3B** - *Manslaughter* - Body Count (2014)
>  **4A** - *Weird Revolution* - Butthole Surfers (2001)
>  **4B** - *Turned On* - Rollins Band (1990)
>  **5A** - *Commercial Entertainment Product* - Emergency Broadcast Network (1992)
>  **5B** - *3* - Violent Femmes (1989)
>
>   As for what *you* are? Until I delve deeper, I'm just going to say you're a Gen Xer. You probably owned some black lace-up boots.
>
>  **Connections:**
>  - Some of these albums have featured people who were, at one point or another, members of Pigface
>
> ## ACTUAL CONNECTION:
>
> All of these bands were [at the first Lollapalooza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Lollapalooza_lineups_by_year#1991)
>
>
>  The "grant" in the title refers to Grant Park in Chicago, the current location of the festival

Comment: What happened to the comments on this one?